# Understanding positioning: adding position absolute to img container, doesn't allow me to margin auto. Why?

Tags: css, css-position, margin

I am trying to understand positioning and I get that when the parent element is positioned relatively you can position children element absolutely. At least I thought I understood this.

I proceeded to give picture element below position:absolute, however when I did this I ran into a problem where I couldn't center the image in mobile view (using media query). I tried to test the centering just normally, but I still couldn't make the image center. I used `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right:auto` under `.img-circle`, but that didn't work.

So I removed `position:absolute` on `.picture` class and then boom it worked. One way or another, I had to then re-position the title class.

It looks like my understanding of positioning is a bit off, could someone please help me understand why the above happened exactly? What I could have done to avoid such a mess, because it took me a while to get it. Thank you!

[codepen project](http://codepen.io/max77p/pen/XdWjGX)

```css
/*.picture{ 
 position:absolute;
  
}*/

.img-circle{
  margin-top:10em;
  width:20em;
  height:20em;
  border:.2em solid;
  border-radius:50%;
  display:block; 
}/*image shape*/
```

```html
<div class="container container-fluid contthird1">
              <div class="picture">
               <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="http://a5.files.biography.com/image/upload/c_fill,cs_srgb,dpr_1.0,g_face,h_300,q_80,w_300/MTE5NTU2MzE2NjUyOTk2MTA3.jpg" class="art">
              </div>
              <!--end of picture-->


              <h3 id="flip">Click to slide the panel right</h3>
        
              <div class="title">
              <p class="lead">I'm a <a class="link" target='_blank' href='http://www.freecodecamp.com/map'>self taught</a> web designer, developer, co-founder and entrepreneur based in Finland.
                <br> I'm currently part of a small web development
                <br> team in an upcoming start-up, building web and
                <br> mobile applications.
                <br>My passion is to use technology based
                <br> solutions, to help solve real world challenges.
                <br> Competences:
                <br> Languages and Frameworks:
                <br> Javascript, HTML5, CSS3, jQuery, Bootstrap3,
                <br> Angular.js, Meteor.js.
                <br> Tools & expertise:
                <br> Git, Responsive Web Design, Agile
                <br> Methodologies.</p>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!--end of container-->
```

Comment: You need to add display:block to the image for the behavior you're describing to apply.

Comment: @frenchie but i do have display:block on the img class above and in the codepen link. Ive tried under the picture class, but it didn't do anything. Only when I removed position:absolute on the picture did everything work

Comment: why did you want to give the image an absolute position? not sure what you were trying to achieve. Absolutely positioned elements are useful for slide shows and such like where content might have to overlap, but I cannot see a reason for it in your codepen. p.s. make `height:auto` to make the image maintain aspect ratio on small screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Margins works fine with relative/static elements. The use of margins for an absolute/fixed element makes no sense since the margins works betweeen elements in the same document flow. When you put `position absolute` you are going out of the normal flow of the document. So you need another solution to center that. This is an example of a simple global perfect center without pre-knowing the sizes of the elements:

```
 .img-circle {
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); /* for iOS devices*/
     transform: translateX(-50%);
 }
```

See it working:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNPLgw

Comment: Not entirely true for margins :)

Comment: @LGSon it works in some cases, but it's obvious that margins in an absolute element makes no sense.If you apply a margin in an absolute element, where margin from what? You can move an absolute element with left, top, bottom, right and makes more sense. Remember that margins includes the modification of the flow (it's not the same `margin-top: -20px` than `top: -20px` for obvious things)

Comment: Agree with you completely, better to use what you suggested, still, it does work so you might want to update your answer

Comment: Ok, you are right. Maybe I need to explain better to avoid confusions. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: However, OP doesn't appears and I don't know if we help him or not.

Comment: Me neither, still, we now covered a few ways to do it ... +1 from me.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude thanks! sorry for delay, been really busy, but i got mine to work and your explanation helped. cheers

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you need to use `left/right`, `margin-left/right` and a `width` to center an element using absolute positioning.

```css
.picture { 
  position: relative; 
}

.img-circle {
  margin-top: 2em;
  height:20em;
  border:.2em solid;
  border-radius:50%;
  display: block; 
  position:absolute;
  /* to vertically center an absolute positioned element below is needed  */
  width: 20em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-fluid contthird1">
  <div class="picture">
    <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="http://a5.files.biography.com/image/upload/c_fill,cs_srgb,dpr_1.0,g_face,h_300,q_80,w_300/MTE5NTU2MzE2NjUyOTk2MTA3.jpg" class="art">
  </div>
  <!--end of picture-->


</div>
<!--end of container-->
```

So even if that is do-able, it's likely not the best solution. What @Marcos suggest is preferable, or using `text-align: center` like below

```css
.picture { 
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-circle {
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 20em;
  height:20em;
  border:.2em solid;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-fluid contthird1">
  <div class="picture">
    <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="http://a5.files.biography.com/image/upload/c_fill,cs_srgb,dpr_1.0,g_face,h_300,q_80,w_300/MTE5NTU2MzE2NjUyOTk2MTA3.jpg" class="art">
  </div>
  <!--end of picture-->


</div>
<!--end of container-->
```